# Removing text-decoration:underline of pre tag inside of underlined block

Tags: html, css

Here's a reproduced example:

```css
div.addu { color: #006e28; text-decoration: underline; }
div.addu blockquote pre { text-decoration: none; }
div.addu blockquote pre code { text-decoration: none; }
div.addu pre, div.rm pre, div.add pre { background-color: #f6f8fa; }
div.addu > blockquote {
border-left: 4px solid #00a000;
padding: 0 15px;
color: #006e28;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="addu">
<pre><code>Underline this code</code></pre>
<p><em>Effects</em>: Equivalent to:</p>
<blockquote>
<pre><code>Do not
Underline
This code</code></pre>
</blockquote>
</div>
```

The early underlined code looks great. The blockquote with the left border looks great. But *why* is the inner code still underlined? Why doesn't the `text-decoration:none;` apply to it? As you can see, I tried to add that in lots of different places, but the top-level `underline` seems to persist. How do I do this right?

Comment: Use `id` to have specific `CSS`. @Barry

Comment: @Vishnudev That's not really a solution. In reality, I have lots of these blocks. I'm not going manually name them and have lots of duplicate style.

Comment: Okay. Use different classes such as `.underline` and `.notunderline`. Separate out into two different `divs` and use these classes seperately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `>` selector of `css` to achieve this, 
No need to change `HTML` or add a class

- Remove `text-decoration` from `div.addu`
- Target `pre` tag using `>` selector and give `text-decoration: underline` to it
- Add `text-decoration: underline;` to `p` tag

```css
div.addu { color: #006e28; }
div.addu p { text-decoration: underline; }
div.addu > pre { text-decoration: underline; }
div.addu blockquote pre { text-decoration: none; }
div.addu blockquote pre code { text-decoration: none; }
div.addu pre, div.rm pre, div.add pre { background-color: #f6f8fa; }
div.addu > blockquote {
border-left: 4px solid #00a000;
padding: 0 15px;
color: #006e28;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="addu">
  <pre>
   <code>strong_ordering operator&lt;=&gt;(const error_code&amp; lhs, const error_code&amp; rhs) noexcept;</code>
  </pre>
  <p>
   <span class="marginalizedparent"><a class="marginalized">8</a></span>
   <em>Effects</em>: Equivalent to:
  </p>
  <blockquote>
   <pre>
 <code>if (auto c = lhs.category() &lt;=&gt; rhs.category(); c != 0) return c;
   return lhs.value() &lt;=&gt; rhs.value();</code>
   </pre>
  </blockquote>
  <pre>
   <code>strong_ordering operator&lt;=&gt;(const error_condition&amp; lhs, const error_condition&amp; rhs) noexcept;</code>
  </pre>
  <p>
   <span class="marginalizedparent"><a class="marginalized">9</a></span>
   <em>Effects</em>: Equivalent to:
  </p>
  <blockquote>
   <pre>
    <code>if (auto c = lhs.category() &lt;=&gt; rhs.category(); c != 0) return c;
   return lhs.value() &lt;=&gt; rhs.value();</code>
   </pre>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the text to still be underlined (the *Effects*: Equivalent to: part), just the inner blockquote to not be.

Comment: @Barry made changes to my answer.. have a look on it

Comment: Works perfectly here, [doesn't quite work here](https://jsfiddle.net/y236gtq5/)? Why doesn't the `p` match? It's like that other `<div />` just breaks things somehow

Comment: No, you need to add the rule for the p tag too you can do that with a comma in CSS @Barry

Comment: @Zuber I know how this site works. Do you know why the added internal `<div>` breaks your answer?

Comment: @weegee i just wanted to be specific so the questioner can understand easily

Comment: @Barry putting `div` inside `p` tag is invalid. you can use `span` instead. please check my updated answer or  https://jsfiddle.net/y4e2mjxs/

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, a no HTML solution or the quickest solution can be to just add this one line `display:inline-block` to `div.addu blockquote pre code` rule in CSS, nothing else changed.

```css
div.addu { color: #006e28; text-decoration: underline; }
div.addu blockquote pre { text-decoration: none; }
div.addu blockquote pre code { text-decoration: none; display:inline-block }
div.addu pre, div.rm pre, div.add pre { background-color: #f6f8fa; }
div.addu > blockquote {
border-left: 4px solid #00a000;
padding: 0 15px;
color: #006e28;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="addu">
<pre><code>Underline this code</code></pre>
<p><em>Effects</em>: Equivalent to:</p>
<blockquote>
<pre><code>Do not
Underline
This code</code></pre>
</blockquote>
</div>
```

Because `text-decoration` applies to only `inline-block` elements, you can just do this